# Postman test - How can I search the entire response for a specific value?

Tags: json, rest, testing, postman

Sorry for the noob question.

Using Postman, how can I search the entire response for a specific value? In this case the value I am using as my assertion would be let’s say “222222”, this has been set as an environment variable (“provId”) in another request and I need to be able to assert that it appears in this second request.

Below is a small snippet of the response I’m working with, the acual response would be much larger and the value “222222” could appear anywhere within.

```json
[   
    {
        “eventId”: “123456”,
        “mappings”: [{
                “provider”: “ABC”,
                “providerId”: “111111”,
                “confidence”: 1.0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        “eventId”: “246810”,
        “mappings”: [{
                “provider”: “ABC”,
                “providerId”: “222222”,
                “confidence”: 1.0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        “eventId”: “135791”,
        “mappings”: [{
                “provider”: “ABC”,
                “providerId”: “333333”,
                “confidence”: 1.0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have managed to write a bit of code to check the correct value from the 1st object (below) but I need it to search the whole response.

```
const body = pm.response.json();
pm.test(“placeholder” + pm.variables.get(“provId”), function() {
pm.response.to.have.jsonBody("[0][mappings].[0][providerId]", 
pm.variables.get(“provId”) );
});
```

Comment: "the value “222222” could appear anywhere within." do you mean anywhere in `providerId` parameter?

Comment: @pavelsaman Hi, thank you for your question and yes, that's correct. The full response would be much larger than the snippet I provided but somewhere in the response the “providerId”: “222222” should appear assuming a "passed" test.

Answer (score 1):

```
let a =
    [
        {
            "eventId": "123456",
            "mappings": [{
                "provider": "ABC",
                "providerId": "111111",
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            "eventId": "246810",
            "mappings": [{
                "provider": "ABC",
                "providerId": "222222",
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            "eventId": "135791",
            "mappings": [{
                "provider": "ABC",
                "providerId": "333333",
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
            ]
        }
    ]


console.log(a.find(elem => elem.mappings[0].providerId === "333333"))
```

use array.find

Update as per comment , if you dont know the mapping index then:

```
console.log(a.find(elem => {
  return elem.mappings.find(items=>items.providerId==="333333")
}
))
```

Comment: This answer requires you to specify an index to help .find locate the correct value among the nested arrays. OP asked how to query the entire response without knowing that. If the answer is to be found in mappings[1], you're not going to find it with this code.

Comment: @Kreidol updated , the ops never got back not sure if thats what ops wanted . As per example mapping only has one item and defined properties

Comment: in the answer provided by ops there they mention mapping[0]

Answer (score 0):

Solution;

```
var resp = pm.response.json();
console.log(resp);
for (var i = 0;i<resp.length;i++)
{
if (resp[i].mappings[0].providerId == pm.variables.get(“provId”))
{
console.log("PASSED TEST : " +resp[i].eventId);
}
else
{
console.log("FAILED TEST : " +resp[i].eventId);
}
}
```